# Integrals - find f given the answer to another integral

Tags: integration

If $f$ is continuous and $\int_0^{36} f(x)dx=6$, find $\int_0^6 xf(x^2)dx$.

I don't know where to start, questions I've done before haven't had the $'x'$ before the $f(x)$.

Comment: Hint: let $t=x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a $u$ substitution. Specifically, if we let $u = x^2$, then $du = 2xdx$. Also, as $x$ ranges between $0$ and $6$ in the second integral, $u$ will range from $0$ to $36$ since $u = x^2$. So we can write the second integral as

$$\int_0^6 x f(x^2)dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{36}f(u)du = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 6 = 3.$$